# How to get the url in browser address bar in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe

I am displaying a page in an iframe, and in my Node.js server I need to access the main page's URL.

I do not want to get the request URL for the page in the iframe, but I need the URL in the browser's address bar, the one for the main page.

Comment: Node.js cannot access anything other than what is in the request, since it's not usually on the same machine as the browser. However, the request URL is the same as what's in the address bar, as far as I know. Is there a case when it isn't?

Comment: @Kendall Frey i have an IFrame, the request comes from iFrame, but I need the browser url instead of where the request actually comes from

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check that I have understood the problem correctly.

Comment: @Kendall Frey thanks for editing. You got it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Referer` request header should contain the URL you are looking for.

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/04/16/getting-the-url-of-an-iframes-parent/

> The HTTP Referer header for a page inside of an iframe is always set to the containing page’s URL.

Answer (score 0):

try the Url module ctrl-f 'pathname' from this page http://nodejs.org/api/url.html